# Missing dependencies in the OpenAPI Generator source code

Tags: java, maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I have downloaded the OpenAPI Generator source code in order to change a few functionalities for my internship.

But in doing so I found that org.openapitools.codegen.meta and the org.openapitools.codegen.api are missing from the openapi-generator project. Is it a bug or problem on my part and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were part of the openapigenerator-core package for me moving the packages to my main project was enough to fix it.